# How to know the system is Debian or CentOS in Python?

Tags: python, debian, centos, yum, apt

I want to write some install scripts by python, it should know the OS to choose either **apt** command or **yum** command.

It seems **sys.platform** can tell **'win32'** or the others, but how to know it is working on  Debian or CentOS in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [platform module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) in the standard library has what you want.

```
import platform
print platform.linux_distribution()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I found `platform.linux_distribution()` is supported from Python 2.6. For the popular CentOS 5.5, because its default Python version is 2.4.3, so, it has to use `platform.dist()`.

Comment: Just as an update, `platform.linux_distribution()` has been depreciated. It is recommended to use PyPI libraries instead, such as distro https://github.com/nir0s/distro, discussion about it https://bugs.python.org/msg207415

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to know whether to use yum or apt, one approach is simply to pick one of those commands and try it.  If it works, it works; if not, catch the exception and try the other command.

Comment: This is certainly the "pythonic" way of doing it... If the OP just wants to choose between `yum`, `apt`, `zypper`, `emerge`, `etc` it's probably the best way.  On the other hand if there is other distro-specific functionality, it may make more sense to use the `platform` module... Either way, +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks too. If there is no good way to differentiate these platforms, i will use your method.